# Как обычно называют эту страницу?

Tags: html

Как называют страницу, на которой есть ответы на часто задаваемые вопросы. Пример прикрепил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычно так и называют — FAQ

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Есть еще такой вариант `ЧаВо` - Часто задаваемые Вопросы...

Comment: Ну и различные Справка, Помощь и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAQ, Справка, ЧаВо (часто задаваемые вопросы) и т.д.